# Css transition doesn't work in action view Rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have been trying to work out why my css transition doesn't work. I use hover.css library to achieve a bounce effect when I hover over the button. But my button does'nt seem to work with action view syntax. Here is my ERB code

```
<h1>Goals</h1>
<div class="row">
<% @goals.each do |goal| %>
  <div class="one-third column" style="border: solid 0.5px #555; border-radius:10px;padding: 20px;">
    <h3><%= goal.title %></h3>
    <p><%= goal.is_goal_validated %></p>
    <p><%= goal.is_goal_completed %></p>
    <p><%= button_to 'Pledge', goal, :method => :get, class: "hvr-bounce-to-right" %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
<button class="hvr-bounce-to-right">hi</button>
</div>
```

And this is my css code

```css
.hvr-bounce-to-right {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
.hvr-bounce-to-right:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #2098d1;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.hvr-bounce-to-right:hover, .hvr-bounce-to-right:focus, .hvr-bounce-to-right:active {
  color: white;
}
.hvr-bounce-to-right:hover:before, .hvr-bounce-to-right:focus:before, .hvr-bounce-to-right:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.52, 1.64, 0.37, 0.66);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.52, 1.64, 0.37, 0.66);
}
```

```html
<button class="hvr-bounce-to-right">hi</button>
```

The thing is that my button html syntax works but not for the action view syntax. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should ask this as a CSS question, your code being generated by rails does not matter. you should also replace the erb code with the generated HTML.

Comment: @Irsyad14 What is your expected output if you press that button?

Comment: There is no such thing as `Action view syntax`. Action view is a templating system that can render ERB, Haml, Slim, jBuilder etc. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_view_overview.html

Comment: @Dinesh just a transition effect when I hover the over the button

Answer (score 2):

So your CSS styles above seem to work just fine at least for a `<button class="hvr-bounce-to-right">hi</button>`

Therefore the problem is likely the ruby code used to generate the buttons. You should check (and post, for that matter) the generated html source of the following line (which I guess results in the buttons that are not working).

```
<%= button_to 'Pledge', goal, :method => :get, class: "hvr-bounce-to-right" %>
```

Comment: yeah, I guess it has something to do with the erb template. Thanks for the heads up anyway

Comment: @Irsyad14 Do you know how you can see the HTML source of your generated page?